# Mutex/semaphore: thread vs process

Tags: multithreading, process, thread-safety, mutex, semaphore

I've worked almost entirely with VxWorks and am thus accustomed to only dealing with threads. I'm now working in a Linux environment where both threads and processes exist, and would like to understand: do mutexes and semaphores work across *processes* in addition to threads?

If they work across *processes*, I'd like to ask further: how does one process "know" that another process is using the same mutex/semaphore? To ask by example, if process A declares global mutex gMutex, and process B also declares global mutex gMutex, don't those two mutexes exist distinct from each other, within each process' respective memory space? I.e. how could a mutex be considered "shared" between two processes any more than a global struct Foo in each process?

I wonder, too, if the term "threadsafety" has thrown me off in thinking mutexes and semaphores perhaps only applied to threads but not processes?

I've tried to do a little bit of reading on the matter, but I get the impression that many people inappropriately use "process" and "thread" interchangeably, so I'm hoping for a targeted answer by asking this question specifically.

Comment: You have to give them a name so the other process can refer to it by name.  Covered pretty well in [this man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html).

Comment: @HansPassant - thank you: very good read.

Comment: @StoneThrow good question and deserved a upvote